# Detect when max limit is reached on JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jspinner

I currently have a `JSpinner` implemented into my form which holds the amount of time taken to do a task; the current limit of this spinner is 180 minutes. My question is how would I detect that the spinner is currently at it's max value so that when the user tries to press the button to increment the amount of minutes I can output a message that notifies them that the max amount of time to perform a task is 180 minutes?

Comment: You should check the current state of the `JSpinner` from the event listener for the button.

Comment: You'd think that the failure of the spinner to advance beyond 180 might be a hint..

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the form. It's not clear what you're displaying to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a JSpinner has reached the limit value, you don't get any more change events from it.

Create a subclass of javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel that has a custom "setValue(..)" method that notifies your code when the UI attempts to set a value that's too large.  Then install it in your JSpinner object with

```
mySpinner.setModel(new MySpinnerModel())
```

But a larger question is whether you should be doing this at all.  A JSpinner has a well-understood UI; people are (meant to be) used to how it performs.  Getting a dialog box that you'll have to dismiss or some other unexpected behavior might not make them happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change listener to your JSpinner component. In its `stateChanged`method you can call the `getNextValue()` method. If this returns `null` then you have reached the max value of the model.

See more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#getNextValue--

Answer (score 0):

I can give a workaround, you just set the limit to 181, and check the value in the changelistener, if it equals to 181, set the value to 180, and perform your method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).